# ngrx ERROR TypeError: action.payload is not iterable

Tags: angular, ngrx

// action

```
export class LoadHerosGeneral implements Action {
  readonly type = HerosActionTypes.LOAD_HEROS_GENERAL;

  constructor(public payload?: IHero[]) {}
}
```

//reducer

```
export function heroGeneral(state = initialStateGneral, action: HerosActions): IHero[] {
  switch (action.type) {
    case HerosActionTypes.LOAD_HEROS_GENERAL:
      console.log(action.payload);
      return [ ...state, ...action.payload ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

// effect

```
getHeros$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
  this.action$.pipe(
    ofType(HerosAction.HerosActionTypes.LOAD_HEROS_GENERAL),
    switchMap(() =>
      this.herosService.getHeros()
        .pipe(
          map((heroGeneral: IHero[]) =>
            new HerosAction.LoadHerosGeneral(heroGeneral)
          ),
          catchError(() =>
            EMPTY
          )
        )
      )
    ),
  );
```

// service I wrapped the service
// get all heros

```
  getHeros(): Observable<IHero[]> {
    return this.generalService.get(`/heroes`);
  }
```

// general service
// GET

```
  get(endpoint, params?, headers?): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.BASE_API_URL + endpoint, {
      ...headers,
      ...params
    })
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.errorHandle)
    );
  }
```

// Component

```
heroGeneral$: Observable<IHero[]>;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<{ heroGeneral: IHero[] }>,
    private herosService: HerosService,
  ) {
    this.heroGeneral$ = store.select('heroGeneral');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHerosData();
  }

  getHerosData(): any {
     this.store.dispatch(new herosActions.LoadHerosGeneral());
    // this.herosService.getHeros().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
```

Seems If I directly use service in my component data works
However, if I dispatch, console show error that

```
ERROR TypeError: action.payload is not iterable
```

The response data should be array

Could any body help me with this bug?
Maybe the effect part?

Thanks.

Comment: If I use IHero rather than IHero[] for the data, then api call work, however, that will be a [object, object] error, I believe I should use IHero[] as my final return data should be array, just like I use service directly, data return is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to specify some `lib` in `tsconfig` to support such iterators.

But you can do a fast fix too, simply turn an empty payload into an empty array.

```
return [ ...state, ...(action.payload || []) ];
```

Comment: could you please help me with this as well?  I stuck below issue
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65595046/angular-ngrx-looping-response-data   thanks