# Angular NGRX looping response data

Tags: angular, ngrx

// action

```
export class LoadPlayersWinLoseCount implements Action {
  readonly type = PlayersActionTypes.LOAD_PLAYERS_WIN_LOSE_COUNT;

  constructor(public accountId, public queryParams, public payload?: IWinlose, ) {}
}
```

// reducer

```
export function playersWinLoseCount(state = initialStateWinLose, action: PlayersActions): IWinlose {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PlayersActionTypes.LOAD_PLAYERS_WIN_LOSE_COUNT:
      console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
      console.log(action.payload);
      return { ...state, ...action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

// effect

```
 getWinLossCount$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(PlayersAction.PlayersActionTypes.LOAD_PLAYERS_WIN_LOSE_COUNT),
    switchMap(({ accountId, queryParams }) =>
      this.playersService.getWinLoseCount(accountId, queryParams)
        .pipe(
          map((playersWinLoseCount: IWinlose )  =>
            new PlayersAction.LoadPlayersWinLoseCount(accountId, queryParams, playersWinLoseCount)
          ),
          catchError(() =>
            EMPTY
          )
        )
      )
    ),
  );
```

// service

```
get(endpoint, params?, headers?): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.BASE_API_URL + endpoint, {
      ...headers,
      ...params
    })
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.errorHandle)
    );
  }



getWinLoseCount(accountId: number, queryParams: IQuery): Observable<IWinlose> {
    return this.generalService.get(`/players/${accountId}/wl`, queryParams);
  }
```

// Component

```
  queryParams;
  playersWinLoseCount$: Observable<IWinlose>;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<{ playersWinLoseCount: IWinlose }>
  ) {
    this.playersWinLoseCount$ = store.select('playersWinLoseCount');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const accountId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe(data => this.queryParams = data);
    this.getWinLossCount(accountId, this.queryParams);
  }

getWinLossCount(accountId, queryParams): any {
    this.store.dispatch(new playersActions.LoadPlayersWinLoseCount(accountId, queryParams));
  }
```

// HTML

```
<div *ngIf="playersGeneral$ | async as players" class="player-hero">
  <img class="player-avatar" [src]="players.profile?.avatarfull"/>
...
```

I read the NGRX doc that if I use `abc$ | async` in THML, then I don't need unsubscribe.
However, now the console.log() debug looping until api call limit.

If I use angular service rather than NGRX, the data response once correct.

Thanks.

Comment: Here looping means endless response data(api call).

Comment: The loop is inside the effect so it seems? ofType(PlayersAction.PlayersActionTypes.LOAD_PLAYERS_WIN_LOSE_COUNT) And when the response is in you dispatch new PlayersAction.LoadPlayersWinLoseCount - which sounds like the same action again?

Comment: please share how `playersGeneral$` looks like

Comment: Sorry for confused. Actually, //HTML should be : <div class="player-win-lose-count" *ngIf="playersWinLoseCount$ | async as playersWinLoseCount"> The same playersWinLoseCount$

Comment: @MikeOne Thanks for the hint. Right my effect should be refactored for the ofType(), if ofType() is same with below new abcAction.LoadBlaBlaBla() and component level dispatch same abcAction.LoadBlaBlaBla() will looping data. Now I definded a Load ofType to dispatch, then at Load ofType, map my load data service new action. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the effects listens on the action it emits itself:

```
PlayersAction.PlayersActionTypes.LOAD_PLAYERS_WIN_LOSE_COUNT
```

and then

```js
new PlayersAction.LoadPlayersWinLoseCount()
```

You need to change this logic to avoid the recursion, or to add a condition when there is no reason to emit the action, for example if the store has have data already.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I do some searching for effect, usually, the effect will listen on the actions for something like Load type, then new abcAction.LoadData(). It's confusing me at the very beginning.

Comment: Usually it should be like - an effect listens on the `load` action, then it sends a request to a backend, and maps response into `upsertItem` or `upsertItems` actions.